# How can I access the object User (django admin) using Group By and Join?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I access the object `user` (from django administration) when I use group by and join?

That my query:

```
Idea.objects.values("author_id").annotate(
        total=Count('author_id'))
```

Running this query, I got this result:

```
<QuerySet [{'author_id': 1, 'total': 6}, {'author_id': 2, 'total': 8}]>
```

However, I can't access the values from `User` (default `User` model from django admin).  In this case, I can access only `author_id` e `total` on my template:

```
{% for d in ideas %}
    {{d.total}} - {{d.author_id}}
 {% endfor %}
```

I can't do something like this: `d.author.user.email`

My model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    use_term_accept = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    manager = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Idea(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('data criação')
    author = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='old_author')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('users.UserProfile', related_name='authors')
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `author__user__email` key to the result by adding `author__user__email` to `values` method.

**Example**:

```
Idea.objects.values("author_id", "author__user__email").annotate(
    total=Count('author_id'))
```